# Aptana and Jaxer

Tags: jaxer

I have been looking for a server side javascript platform and seen references to Aptana Jaxer which looked ideal, but the Jaxer aspect appears not to be supported any more, is this correct?

I have seen the Jaxer site and installed the standalone server and it looks excellent but cannot see where (or why) I would use Aptana if it doesn't integrate with it or have I missed something?

I am trying to avoid the effort learning a technology that is no longer supported?

Regards

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Jaxer is dead.

I've explained my reasoning elsewhere in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095793/web-host-with-jaxer/2103165#2103165).

Comment: Thanks very much, this is what I had concluded.

I am still looking for a mechanism to run SSJS so I guess I keep looking! On another tack, broadly speaking Aptana is an environment to help creating HTML5 webstes, yes? I have put the Studio 3 plugin into my Eclipse distro and the additional functionality seems to be around having a JS perspective, yes? I don't write Rails or PHP sites sites this is not of use to me.